# What has happened with the investigation of mtgox.com?

Tags: mtgox

Why hasn't there been any update since 9th of September 2015? What has happened since then?

Comment: Also see: https://www.reddit.com/r/mtgoxinsolvency/

Comment: 17th February is next creditor's meeting. Expect nothing.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the latest official news is the article [After the CEO’s Indictment the Great Mt. Gox Bitcoin Mystery Deepens](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/09/14/after-the-ceo-s-indictment-the-great-mt-gox-bitcoin-mystery-deepens.html) from the 14th of September 2015, and these two tweets:

> PDG #Français de MtGox,banque #BTC basé à #Tokyo sera condamné sans jugement sur des charges n'ayant aucun lien avec disparition 50,000,000$ – [@NathalieStucker (Jan 7th 2016)](https://twitter.com/NathalieStucky/status/685247598291103744)

and

> 30歳のフランス人が6ヶ月間以上東京の #刑務所 に #永遠 と取調べられてるため、#外国メディア は日本の #司法制度 に #疑問。23日間の #保管期間、#人権 にかかわる。– [@NathalieStucker (Jan 9th 2016)](https://twitter.com/NathalieStucky/status/685746820509601792)

You can follow Nathalie Stucky on Twitter [@NathalieStucker](https://twitter.com/NathalieStucky) and as a contributor on [Daily Beast](http://www.thedailybeast.com/contributors/nathalie-kyoko-stucky.html), she seems to be the only one interested in truth and justice on this topic.

Now a few unofficial news, AFAIK Mark Karpelès hasn't been allowed any visits, not even contacts with his family and is not allowed to use a computer either. 
 He already lost 35 kg but still hasn't accepted to be the scapegoat, which seems to be why he's still detained after more than 4 months, without any trial or official charges…

Comment: Hi @neofutur, could you please add a sentence of summary to each link? Without clicking the links it is not clear what information they are leading to. Also, the date of your "latest news" seems to align with what the asker is referring to as his last information.

Comment: the links are juste the tweets from the only ( french/english/japanese speaking ) journalist that seem to be interested in the topic. i have nothing better to add than my unofficial news at the end.

Comment: Either the links are relevant and it would be useful to provide summaries/translations, or they aren't and they shouldn't clutter up the answer. :)

Comment: i didnt know on stackexchange you had to copy paste the content from other websites, is that a new rule ?

Comment: you don't have to. But leaving a whole bunch of links without any indication why anyone should click them compounds to making a post much less useful. Especially when the link target is gone for some reason after some time, no information is left.